# Navigating to .git project directory

Tags: git, directory, commit

I am new to Git and I am working my way through a tutorial for beginners.
Currently I am attempting to navigate to my projects root directory.
The tutorial is mainly for people who use a Mac and currently I am using Windows so it can get a bit confusing.
It is telling me to execute "ls -C .git"
Which should lead to something like:

```
COMMIT_EDITMSG  ORIG_HEAD   index       objects
HEAD        config      logs        refs
```

However Git is telling me that ls is not a command. I have tried "git ls" but can't figure out the right command to get to the root directory. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What git wrapper are you using? Git Bash? Or just a standard Windows command prompt?

Comment: Just a standard windows command prompt

Comment: Git Bash is your friend, and not only for Git stuff. And since its default GUI container is inconvenient as hell, better even get yourself a ConEmu and set git bash as one of the shells it can run. That's my daily setup at work (git bash being the default shell in my ConEmu), and it alleviates a lot of the pain of working in command line under Windows. :) http://conemu.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a standard Windows command prompt, you won't be able to use the unix (read: Mac/Linux) `ls` command, and you'll want to use the Windows equivalent of `dir` instead.

Try the command `dir .git` from within your git repository. This should list all the files in the `.git` folder, and should output something similar to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the git project directory will take a combination of commands.

I'm sure you have first been asked to do something like this:

```
git init myproject
```

So ls would be used to list all of the files in your current working directory.

By using a combination of

```
cd some_subdirectory
```

to make your new working directory the subdirectory, and

```
cd ..
```

to navigate up a directory you will eventually get to the folder where git created your new project under source control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a windows command prompt, where as the tutorial is intended for a unix-like shell environment, where `ls` is a valid command.  The equivalent command in `DOS`(Windows command prompt) is `dir`.

However, I'd highly recommend that you install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or another similar Unix emulator for this.  It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thought 'ls' is a Unix command, you can have it on Windows if you open a powershell console instead of a 'cmd' console. But perhaps you won't have all the same options, so it shouldn't be a sustainable solution.

Opening a bash command installed with git appears to be a much better solution.

But if you like powershell, you could install and use 'posh-git'.